# Heating metal with laser?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, laser, laser-interaction

Can a laser be used to heat metal's to the point they glow red?
How are laser cutters able to cut metal very easily?
How much heat can a laser generate?

Comment: The answer is yes. You question is very basic. Please read wikipedia and http://www.coherent.com/applications/index.cfm?fuseaction=Forms.page&PageID=98 and ask more questions.

Comment: Discussions of "how much" is totally pointless without real values.  How fast is a car?  How long is a string?  How big is a large rock?  This unscientific nonsense doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 3):

- Can a laser be used to heat metal's to the point they glow red?

Yes

- How much heat can a laser generate?

How big can it be? [What laser are you talking about](http://phys.org/news/2012-07-nif-history-terawatt-laser-shot.html)?

- How are laser cutters able to cut metal very easily?

Now that is a good question.

Some laser cutters will melt the object they are cutting to cut them.  More sophisticated laser cutters, and more energy efficient, use [ultra short pulses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrashort_pulse) to create [ablation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_ablation). Ultra short pulsed laser ablation, typically converts a very specific amount of material into a plasma. This will allow scanning devices to verify the results before new pulse(s) are sent to cut more.

Comment: Ah a material is used, which explains it. There was a metal cutter that uses 150W, I saw that impossible that amount of power able to cut iron?! However, it seems that the CO2 played a role here.

Comment: The material I was talking about was the material to be cut. No material is used up other than the material cut, unless you include the wear and tear of time on the laser device. BTW: You probably want a solid state laser over a CO2 laser, but that all depends on what you plan to do, and how much you want to pay. Just saying a CO2 laser is like a light-bulb, a solid state laser is like a diode, which one do you think will last?

Comment: Laser can cut throw metal that easily? With low amounts of power that's remarkable. To think if it can cut throw the metal certainly it can heat it up super fast correct?

Comment: Yes, it will cut with precision. And it does not have to melt it, so the heat is used efficiently. Basically the metal in most cases will simply be warm to the touch afterward, not hot.

Comment: Well in that case, lasers are fast methods of heating metals super fast? I mean, if it can cut it that fast, certainly it can heat it up very quickly to the point where it glows.

Comment: Yeh, I don't think I understood your goal. I was talking about industrial lasers for manufacturing. Why would anyone want to use a laser to make metal glow if they can just use an arch welder. If the goal is simply to make metal glow, I would not recommend using a laser, but if you had to, then a CO2 laser would be a good option.